# Need query result that doesn't start and end with "A" or "a" letter

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to write a query that returns list of customer names that do not start or end with letter "A" (either in upper case or lower case). Following is my query,

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE 
CustomerName IN (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE 'A%') 
AND 
CustomerName IN (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE '%a')
```

In the query result, I am getting an "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)". Columns of Customers table is

```
`customers` (
  `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

Can someone please correct my query?

Comment: (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE 'A%')
This is a subquery and you must need to return any single record only. You can't return more then 1 data in this.

Comment: Both the subquery's are getting executed independently. I want to combine both subqueries resut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sub query adds is like adding extra calculation which will utilize more resources.

This can be achieved using a simple where clause like this:

```
select
    *
from
    Customers
where
    upper(CustomerName) not like 'A%'
    and upper(CustomerName) not like '%A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way, It will take care of case sensitive as well.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustomerName  NOT LIKE 'A%'  AND CustomerName  NOT LIKE '%A'
```

You don't need to perform subquery for this.

Comment: I also want CustomerName not to end with a. So, I included '%a'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers 
WHERE 
CustomerName NOT LIKE 'A%'
AND 
CustomerName NOT LIKE '%a'
```

you dont need subquery.

if you want to use subquery you code should like bellow,

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE 
CustomerName IN (SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE 'A%') 
AND 
CustomerName IN (SELECT  CustomerName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName NOT LIKE '%a')
```

"But in here you dont need that.

"So you should define in subquery what you want after the SELECT.